# UITableViewCell selectedBackground shadow not displayed on device

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, uitableview, calayer

[image: Image showing shadow for selected cell on Simulator but not on Device]

This one has me thrown and I'm wondering if anyone can help. I am trying to display a shadow on my selected UITableViewCell and it works fine on the Simulator but not on my iPad 3rd Gen running iOS 7.0.4

I have a subclassed UITableViewCell which is alloc/initting a subclassed UIView as its selectedBackground. All works fine other than it not displaying on the Device.

In my subclassed UITableViewCell...

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.selectedBackgroundView = [[OTHD_CellSelectedView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];

}
```

And in my OTHD_CellSelectedView...

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self createLayer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) createLayer
{
    CALayer *the_layer = [CALayer layer];
    [self.layer insertSublayer:the_layer atIndex:0];

    the_layer.frame = self.bounds;
    the_layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    the_layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    the_layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    the_layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
    the_layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
}
```

Comment: As an experiment try declaring CALayer *the_layer as a property instead and make it strong reference. Does it change anything?

Comment: Have you tried on another device? It may be that the graphics on that retina 3rd gen iPad aren't up to supporting some of the visual effects. The simulator is generally a dangerous guide to UI efficiency and support as it'll use the full resources of the Mac to do it's thing.

Comment: @Tander, thanks for the suggestion but no, this changes nothing.

Comment: @Cocoadelica, it could be that this would work on another device but it is fairly minimal use of a CALayer and I really do need to support all iPads that run iOS7.

Comment: Have you tried it on a later device? iPhone 4S / iPhone 5s?

Comment: @Tander, tried on iPhone 5s and it's same as on iPad.

Comment: Just followed your steps, and it works fine for me. I get the shadow both in the simulator (building for iOS 7.1) and on my 5S. Have you tried creating a new project with only the bare essentials to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should bringToFront the cell in Table I have tried this and it is working for me... I hope this will help you:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == selected)
    {
        cell.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        cell.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
        cell.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
        cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;

        [cell.superview bringSubviewToFront:cell];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
    }


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selected = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadData];

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimationNone)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rajesh, this is changing the cell's layer rather than the cell's selectedBackgroundView.layer but if this is what I need to do to get it working then so be it.